# Updating text in tkinter following enter key press

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, enter

I'm trying to make a simple GUI in tkinter that shows an equation, the user writes a response, and if they're correct and hit enter, it refreshes with a new equation.

[image: Example]

I have a list of equations and correct answers but I'm really way out of my depth here. I was trying to write this code with my daughter so she could help my son with his math but I have become stuck on so many points. I don't know how to have the enter keystroke lead to a command, I don't know how to update the equation, and I don't know how to test the equation and answer combination.

Anyone know of a good tutorial we could reference?

Comment: post the code..

Comment: There are literally hundreds of online tkinter tutorials and references — just search for them using your favorite search engine.

Comment: You can have an "event handler" function—which you wrote—called whenever the user presses the Enter key (which causes a certain kind of user [event](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/events.html) to be created and processed. You can associate or `bind()` an event-handler with a specific [`Text`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text.html) widget if you wish, or the whole application.

Comment: For a good tutorial on how employ tkinter see [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/index.html). The section on events is most helpful.

Comment: @itprorh66: I have a direct link to the section on events in my 2nd comment. I wouldn't call it a tutorial, but a fairly good reference — although over the years I found out it's missing a few important details.

Comment: @martineau, I guess I have to agree with you, it is however a good overall introduction to tkinter and I find it has many of the answers  tkinter developers need to understand in order to create a solid tkinter GUI.  I also agree there are many other sources that cover the details in more depth.